# Remote Control (from the webpage) for a Media Player on remote machine?

Tags: php, controls, media-player, flowplayer

I just want a interface like a controller which can control "Play/Pause/Stop/ ..etc" for some kind of player (Flash or anything else) playing on a remote server, across "HTTP" under same domain.

With simple words, i just wanna control a video playing on a remote machine, but "controller" side must be on a webpage.

+++++++ Web Server ++++++++  <---<---< +++++++ Client Web Page +++++++++
+++++ PLAYING VIDEO ++++++++ .............. ++++ with REMOTE CONTROL +++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++ ............... +++[ PLAY / STOP / NEXT / PREV ]+++++

- Is it possible?
- Player playing over server will be displaying on a "Web Page" normally but.. **is it possible for some kind of "Desktop Player"** ?
- For Webpage, which "Player" should i use, A Flash Player (like, Flowplayer) / A Plugin (like, VLC Plugin) ?

P.S: Prefer "PHP" for server side

Comment: Its not possible to control a bog standard flash player from a separate window, unless you specificity coded the player to listen for an event from a control file on your server, it it possible to control the vlc binary from a web page as it has an interface listen for events, tho I have not played with it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just modified the question above. Please kindly read the question above again. (In brief, is it possible to control for a Desktop Player, from a web page?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done with VLC:

**Click:** View -> Add Interface -> Web Interface
Then Visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser, the first page controls the playback of the binary player (Like a remote control).

Also a neat little feature is the flash player: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/flash.html` it will stream the video on the page with Flow Player, im pretty sure thats what your looking for. Visit the link below for more info about setting it up and the various options.
[wiki.videolan.org/Interface](http://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_via_a_browser)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with the help of Ajax + jPlayer.

Essentially what you are going to want to do is set up jPlayer on page1 to keep calling a php file on your backend that checks for any new commands. Here it is a pseudo code, if you need more help I can write actual code that does it.

page1.php

- calls api.php every 5 seconds and expects a JSON obj back
- has functions setup to pass commands received from the AJAX call to jPlayer

page2.php

- Has buttons/links/whatever that call api.php and set

api.php

- 2 purposes, set and retrieve data
- When asked to set data it writes a command to the DB
- When asked to retrive data is queries the DB for all un-run queries (Field that is true/false) and then updates the DB to set those command to "ran" so that they are only executed once

Here is how it would look in practice

- page1 is loaded and video starts playing while checking api.php every 5 seconds via AJAX
- page2 calls api.php and tells it to pass on the command "pause"
- api updates the DB with the command "pause"
- page1's AJAX call hits api.php which in turn checks the DB, returns "pause", then updated the DB the mark "pause" as already ran

Of course know that you will need to protect against SQL injection via api.php as you don't want some attacker to send a fake command to api.php. To protect against this I would suggest whitelisting commands (play, pause, next, prev, skip to, etc) so that there is a limit to what your script is capable of.

Comment: Oh really? Does jPlayer has that control events? And.. please kindly read the question above again. (In brief, is it possible to control for a Desktop Player (on server), from a web page?)

Comment: I missed the "desktop" part, sorry about that. jPlayer is HTML5/javascript based player with flash fallbacks if needed. It allows you to completely control it via javascript.

What "Desktop Player" are you trying to control? VLC allows for complete control via its web interface